# How to implement the arnold transform of image

Tags: transformation

I need to implement the arnold transformation on colour image as it is part of my project please suggest how to implement it for MxN image

Answer (score 1):

In the classical sense, the continuous Arnold's map is defined on the unit square, and therefore the discrete version is defined on square images:

Consider your image as three NxN matrices; one NxN matrix for each colour channel (assuming you're working with RGB images). Do the following transformation with each of the matrices:

*Map the (i,j) element of the input matrix to the ((i + j) mod N, (i + 2j) mod N) element of the output matrix.*

It's a concatenation of a vertical and a horizontal shearing transformation, "wrapped around" to the original image rectangle:

[image: Arnold map]

(the image is from the [corresponding Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map))

In pseudocode for a single colour channel:

```
Image arnold(inputImage){
    outputImage = Image(inputImage.width, inputImage.height);

    for(x = 0; x < inputImage.width; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < inputImage.height; y++){
            pixel = inputImage[x][y];
            outputImage[(2*x + y) mod inputImage.width][(x + y) mod inputImage.height] = pixel;
        }
    }
    return outputImage;
}
```

*(note that conventionally we index matrices by (row,column) and images by (column,row))*

So that's for square (NxN) images. What you want (Arnold's map for MxN images, where possibly M != N) is somewhat ill-posed in the sense that it's not clear whether it preserves [some interesting properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map#Properties) of Arnold's map. However, if that doesn't bother you, you can generalize the map for MxN images the following way:

1. Perform a vertical shear with wrap-around in such a way, that the j-th column is circulalry shifted upward by j*M/N (note that this leaves the first column and the last column in-place) *
2. Perform a horizontal shear with wrap-around in such a way, that the i-th row is circulalry right-shifted by i*N/M (this leaves the first and the last row in-place) *

* : shearing is simply shifting columns/rows

Edit: updated my answer for the generalized MxN case